# LDAP Query Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap, query

I need to create an ldap searchbase to get all members of a group. So far i have this query but this give me all the information about the members in the group. I only want the sAMaccountName of users. How can i make the query that it only outputs the sAMaccountName  of the members of the group?

```
ldifde -d "DC=domain,DC=nl" -f c:\output.txt -r "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=Local Group,OU=Applications,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=nl)
```

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer it was kind of obvious -l parameter.

Comment: @Wouter Why don't you write the full answer if you found a solution to your question